# loop calculation as it go in r

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am having difficulty executing a calculation that is defined iteratively.  The following data serves as an example (actual data set much larger):

```
## DATA ##
# Columns
   Individual<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H1","H2","H3","H4","H5","K1","K2","K3","K4","K5")
   P1<-c(0,0,"A",0,"C","C",0, rep("E",5),"H1","H2","H3","H4","H5")
   P2<-c(0,0,"B",0,"D", "E",0,rep("G",5),"H1","H2","H3","H4","H5")
# Dataframe
   myd<-data.frame(Individual,P1,P2,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


   Individual P1 P2
1           A  0  0
2           B  0  0
3           C  A  B
4           D  0  0
5           E  C  D
6           F  C  E
7           G  0  0
8          H1  E  G
9          H2  E  G
10         H3  E  G
11         H4  E  G
12         H5  E  G
13         K1 H1 H1
14         K2 H2 H2
15         K3 H3 H3
16         K4 H4 H4
17         K5 H5 H5
```

The data represents the relationship between and Individual and the two parents, `P1`, `P2`.

The calculation required, labeled `relationA`, represents how much each individual is related to A.

By definition, the relationship between A and A is given a value of 1. The values for all other individuals need to be computed based on the information in the table, as follows:

```
The value of relationA for an individual should be equal to 
   1/2 (the value of relationA of P1 of the individual)  
 + 1/2 (the value of relationA of P2 of the individual)
```

FOR EXAMPLE

```
  Individual P1 P2      relationA
1           A  0  0       1
2           B  0  0       0
3           C  A  B       (A = 1 + B = 0)/2 = 0.5
4           D  0  0       0
5           E  C  D       (C= 0.5 + D = 0)/2 = 0.25
6           F  C  E       (C = 0.5 + E = 0.25)/2 = 0.375
```

The expected output is as the following:

```
 Individual P1 P2  relationA
1           A  0  0   1
2           B  0  0   0
3           C  A  B   0.5
4           D  0  0   0
5           E  C  D   0.25
6           F  C  E   0.375
7           G  0  0   0 
8          H1  E  G   0.125
9          H2  E  G   0.125
10         H3  E  G   0.125
11         H4  E  G   0.125
12         H5  E  G   0.125
13         K1 H1 H1   0.125
14         K2 H2 H2   0.125
15         K3 H3 H3   0.125
16         K4 H4 H4   0.125
17         K5 H5 H5   0.125
```

My difficulty is in expressing this in a proper manner in `R`.   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I want to create a loop that can perform similar calculations in large dataset like this... unfortunately no idea

Comment: Still not sure I understand what you're looking for, but you may want to look at the ifelse() and apply() functions.

Comment: @screechOwl please see my edited version

Comment: There is no need to downvote the question.  It is a legitimate question.  The problem is simply one of the english language.  Perhaps instead of downvoting we can make a better effort to understand questions that, although may be poorly phrased, still show a true need.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, I've retracted my downvote, but did you see the original question?  It wasn't a question.

Comment: @GSee The original question was certainly hard to comprehend. But down voting it indicates to others that the question isn't worth wasting time on.  The language barrier makes it more difficult to comprehend, but not any less worthy of one's time.

Comment: Until the OP edited it to make it a question, I don't think it was worth anyone's time, but perhaps I overvalue other people's time.

Comment: I appreciate both you (RicardoSaporta and GSee) for your time and helping in improvement and answering the question. It was my fault as I did not know how to write to a broad audiance .. sometime it is difficult to know whether others are understanding your problem unless somebody caution you ... although I do not mind negative vote but simple note as ScreechOwl was helpful to know question need an improvement ... thanks everybody

Comment: @Shamil, no problem.  Were you able to get the results you needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Edit:

more succinctly, you could use `sapply` and `rowSums` to do away with the `for-loop` into a single line of code:

```
# Initialize values of relationA
myd$relationA <- 0
myd$relationA[myd$Individual=="A"] <- 1

# Calculate relationA
myd$relationA <-   myd$relationA + rowSums(sapply(myd$Individual, function(indiv) 
     myd$relationA[myd$Individual==indiv]/2 * ((myd$P1==indiv) + (myd$P2==indiv))))
```

---

Is what you are looking for something like this?

```
# Initialize values of relationA
myd$relationA <- 0
myd$relationA[myd$Individual=="A"] <- 1


# Iterate over all Individuals
for (indiv in myd$Individual) {

  indiVal <- myd$relationA[myd$Individual==indiv]

  # all columns handled at once, thanks to vectorization;  no need for myd$P1[i]
  myd$relationA <- myd$relationA  + 
                 indiVal/2 * ((myd$P1==indiv) + (myd$P2==indiv))
}
```

**Output**

```
myd
   Individual P1 P2 relationA
1           A  0  0     1.000
2           B  0  0     0.000
3           C  A  B     0.500
4           D  0  0     0.000
5           E  C  D     0.250
6           F  C  E     0.375
7           G  0  0     0.000
8          H1  E  G     0.125
9          H2  E  G     0.125
...
```

Comment: Thanks, please see my recent edits .....when I tried the loop you suggested I am getting "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Value", value = numeric(0)) :   replacement has 0 rows, data has 17", am I missing something ? and the output value are also different

Comment: @sharnil Whoops!  I forgot to copy and paste the first two lines.  I edited the answer now with the corrected lines, and also changed the variable name from `values` to `relationA`

Answer (score 4):

You can write a function to compute the value given an individual and (implicitly) the relationships as a simple recursive function.

```
relationA <- function(ind) {
  if(ind == "A") {
    1
  } else if (ind == "0") {
    0
  } else {
    pts <- myd[myd$Individual == ind,]
    (relationA(pts[["P1"]]) + relationA(pts[["P2"]])) / 2
  }
}
```

Simply, if the individual is A, it is 1; if the individual is 0, it is 0; for anything else, recursively call `relationA` for each parent (`P1` and `P2`) corresponding to the individual and add those together and divide by 2.  This only works for a single individual at a time:

```
> relationA("A")
[1] 1
> relationA("F")
[1] 0.375
> relationA("K5")
[1] 0.125
```

but you can vectorize it over all the individuals relatively easily:

```
> sapply(myd$Individual, relationA)
    A     B     C     D     E     F     G    H1    H2    H3    H4    H5    K1 
1.000 0.000 0.500 0.000 0.250 0.375 0.000 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 
   K2    K3    K4    K5 
0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125
```

and this can be assigned back to `myd` with

```
myd$relationA <- sapply(myd$Individual, relationA)
```

This is not particularly efficient because it has to compute `relationA` over and over again for each case. When it gets to "K5", it calls `reationA("H5")` twice, each of which call `relationA("E")` and `relationA("G")`, and those call `relationA("C")`, `relationA("D")`, `relationA("0")` and `relationA("0")`, etc.. That is, no results are cached but rather recomputed each time. For this small of a data set, it doesn't matter because even inefficient is still very fast.

If you want/need to cache the results and use that cache, then you can modify `relationA` to do so.

```
relationAc <- function(ind) {
  pts <- myd[myd$Individual == ind,]
  if(nrow(pts) == 0 | any(is.na(pts[["relationA"]]))) {
    relationA <-
      if(ind == "A") {
        1
      } else if (ind == "0") {
        0
      } else {
        (relationAc(pts[["P1"]]) + relationAc(pts[["P2"]])) / 2
      }
    myd[myd$Individual == ind, "relationA"] <<- relationA
    relationA
  } else {
    pts[["relationA"]]
  }
}
```

You do then have to initialize the cache:

```
myd$relationA <- NA_real_
```

A single call will fill in the needed values, and calling for the entire set of individuals will result in all the values being filled in.

```
> myd
   Individual P1 P2 relationA
1           A  0  0        NA
2           B  0  0        NA
3           C  A  B        NA
4           D  0  0        NA
5           E  C  D        NA
6           F  C  E        NA
7           G  0  0        NA
8          H1  E  G        NA
9          H2  E  G        NA
10         H3  E  G        NA
11         H4  E  G        NA
12         H5  E  G        NA
13         K1 H1 H1        NA
14         K2 H2 H2        NA
15         K3 H3 H3        NA
16         K4 H4 H4        NA
17         K5 H5 H5        NA
> relationAc("K5")
[1] 0.125
> myd
   Individual P1 P2 relationA
1           A  0  0     1.000
2           B  0  0     0.000
3           C  A  B     0.500
4           D  0  0     0.000
5           E  C  D     0.250
6           F  C  E        NA
7           G  0  0     0.000
8          H1  E  G        NA
9          H2  E  G        NA
10         H3  E  G        NA
11         H4  E  G        NA
12         H5  E  G     0.125
13         K1 H1 H1        NA
14         K2 H2 H2        NA
15         K3 H3 H3        NA
16         K4 H4 H4        NA
17         K5 H5 H5     0.125
> sapply(myd$Individual, relationAc)
    A     B     C     D     E     F     G    H1    H2    H3    H4    H5    K1 
1.000 0.000 0.500 0.000 0.250 0.375 0.000 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 
   K2    K3    K4    K5 
0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 
> myd
   Individual P1 P2 relationA
1           A  0  0     1.000
2           B  0  0     0.000
3           C  A  B     0.500
4           D  0  0     0.000
5           E  C  D     0.250
6           F  C  E     0.375
7           G  0  0     0.000
8          H1  E  G     0.125
9          H2  E  G     0.125
10         H3  E  G     0.125
11         H4  E  G     0.125
12         H5  E  G     0.125
13         K1 H1 H1     0.125
14         K2 H2 H2     0.125
15         K3 H3 H3     0.125
16         K4 H4 H4     0.125
17         K5 H5 H5     0.125
```